# $10000$ binary values get the frequency $1$ to $n$th

Tags: probability, statistics, graphing-functions

I have an exercise of probability I am trying to solve :

We have a sequence of $10000$ equiprobable binary values and we write $f_n$ the frequency from $1$ up to the $n$th value. What is the sequence $g_n = 2 f_n - n$ and plot the graphic. So my question in order to call the function plot$(x,y)$ we have to know the $f_n$ and $g_n$ as functions. So we need the law of probability. I am blocked with this step. Any idea is welcomed. Thank you very much .

Comment: I have edited abit your question, let me know if somehow I did it wrong. Can you also clarify a little about that line: "So my question in order.."?

Comment: @Dahaka it's excellent better then that is not possible :) thank you very much I 'm new and I don't know how to write very good using all the math symbols&language

Comment: Yes I have to determine the functions fn,gn and I don't know how to do it . The final step is to plot the 2 functions but this is the conclusion I think .